# multiple http.post in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, httpclient

I am trying to send an http.post request for each element of an array, my method works well, but when I subscribe, it does it for each of the requests, if someone could help me optimize this, I will I would really appreciate it, here I leave the snippets of my code.

component.ts

```
saveExclusion() {
this.indForm.value.Centers.forEach(element => {
  for (const days of this.exclusionDays) {
    delete days.horadesde;
    delete days.horahasta;
    delete days.id;
    for (const key in days) {
      if (days[key] === true) {
        days[key] = true;
      }else if (days[key] === false) {
        delete days[key];
      }
    }
  }
  const valueForm = this.indForm.value;
  valueForm.ResourceId = this.idResource;
  valueForm.TimeZoneId = 'America/Santiago';
  valueForm.CenterId = element;
  this.exclusionFunc = false;
  this.apiFca.saveNew(valueForm, this.exclusionDays)
    .pipe(last()).subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res)
      if (res === '200') {
        this.successMessage = true;
        this.exclusionDays = [];
        this.indForm.reset();
        this.ngOnInit();
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.successMessage = false;
        }, 3000);
      }
    }, err => {
      console.log('error', err);
    });
});
```

}

service.ts

```
saveNew(exclusionData, daysBlock) {
  let reason = '';
  const dt = new Date();
  const n = dt.getTimezoneOffset();
  const tz = new Date(n * 1000).toISOString().substr(14, 5);
  if (exclusionData.OtherReason) {
    reason = exclusionData.ExclusionReason + ' ' + exclusionData.OtherReason;
  } else {
    reason = exclusionData.ExclusionReason;
  }
  if (exclusionData.ExclusionType !== 'Partial' ) {
    daysBlock = [];
  }
  const data = {Exclusion: new ExclusionClass(
   [],
   reason,
   exclusionData.ExclusionType,
   exclusionData.Repetition,
   exclusionData.CenterId,
   exclusionData.ProfessionalName,
   exclusionData.ResourceId,
   daysBlock,
   exclusionData.TimeZoneId,
   'Exclude',
   exclusionData.Unit,
   exclusionData.ValidFrom + 'T' + exclusionData.ValidTimeFrom + ':00-' + tz,
   exclusionData.ValidTo + 'T' + exclusionData.ValidTimeUntil + ':59.999-' + tz
  )};
  if (exclusionData.CenterId === '') {
    delete data.Exclusion.CenterId;
  }
  return this.http
      .post("url", data)
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
          return res.code;
        })
      );
}
```

greetings, and I look forward to your comments, thanks.

Comment: You can try [`combineLatest()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest)

Comment: How could I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not fully confident in my rxjs knowledge but it looks like, because of `.pipe(last())`, you are only watching the last request? I'd recommend you only set success if all completed without error, like

```
this.apiFca.saveNew(valueForm, this.exclusionDelays)
    .subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log(res);
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
        },
        () => {
            this.successMessage = true;
            // etc. etc. etc.
        });
```

or maybe instead of using `this.successMessage` use something like `this.saveState$` that would be the a BehaviorSubject object initialized with 'idle' (or some enum thereof) that your `saveExclusion()` function manages. That way, the beginning of your `saveExclusion()` function could

1. set `const saveState$ = this.saveState$`
2. assert that `saveState$.getValue() === 'in process'` or if not, do something about it,
3. `saveState$.next('in process');`

and you could change your subscribe line to

```
this.apiFca.saveNew(valueForm, this.exclusionDelays)
.subscribe(
    res => {
        if (res !== '200') {
            saveState$.next('unexpected result')
    }   },
    err => {
        console.log(err);
        saveState$.next('error');
    },
    () => {
        if (saveState$.getValue() === 'in process') {
            saveState$.next('success');
    }   }
);
```

And then you can subscribe to your component's `saveState$` as well (though outside of the component you'd want to provide `saveState$.asObservable()` so values can't be injected by outside code). This affords some elegant event-driven code in your component initialization:

```
saveState$.pipe(filter(val => val === 'error'))
.subscribe(functionToTellYourUserThereWasAnError);

// if successful, we want other code to know, but immediately change it back to 'idle' even if other code errors
saveState$.pipe(filter(val => val === 'success')
.subscribe(val => saveState$.next('idle'));

// upon success, reset me
saveState$.pipe(filter(val => val === 'success'))
.subscribe(
    val => {
        this.exclusionDays = [];
        // etc. etc.
        // setTimeout not needed because set to 'idle' in a different thread.
    }
)
```

Plus, I think your template could reflect and change the UI in response to changes in `saveState$` as well, so your save button can be enabled/disabled based on whether or not saveState is 'idle', etc.

Comment: I've been thinking more about this! `this.apiFca.saveNew(valueForm, this.exclusionDelays).subscribe(...` might be improved?  `this.apiFca.saveNew(valueForm, this.exclusionDelays).pipe(map(res => res.code), every(code => code === 200), takeUntil(saveState$))` will emit a success/fail Boolean, and abort if saveState$ is changed by something else. Just a thought. Keep or toss.

Comment: Also, [read this](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87). I think we're both being inelegant, here. Wouldn't it be better if the service returns an observer, and the component wires things up so an observable of save requests does a `mapTo` of whatever the service needs and then subscribes the service to it? One subscribe **for the life of the component** rather than one per save request?